# Android socket send big image and lose data

Tags: android, send, image

Now it is sent image between terminals. The client translates the picture into byte stream and then distribute to server. The server finds to send people and send the data to terminal. Now send the big picture in two station simulator of LAN. 
There is no problem in Send and Receive. Deployed to the network server, Server receives the code.

```
int length = 0;
int totalNum = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((length = dis.readInt()) != 0) {
    length = dis.read(buffer, 0, length);
    System.out.println("length :-------->" + length);

    totalNum += length;
    out.writeInt(length);
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    out.flush();
}
System.out.println("totalNum:-------->" + totalNum);
out.writeInt(0);
out.flush();
Debug.info("totalNum::::" + totalNum);
initService.getEnterpriseMsgService().save(msg);
```

It receives 1024 bytes every time. Sometimes to `System.out.println("length :-------->" + length);` it is null. Emulator send and receive data is consistent every time. When I send big picture, it is not has the problem. I don not know whether it is about the code or server problem.

Ask for solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case of sending and receiving image.You must increase your buffer size

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try this way:

```
InputStream is //your InputStream
OutputStream out //your OutputStream
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length = 0;
try {
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```